# math function in cuda

Tags: c++, cuda

When I use cuda Mathematical Functions(like fmax(double, double), exp(double))in a kernel function, how can I make sure that the compiler doesn't confuse the c/c++ built-in function with the same name?(fmax(), exp() also exist in c++ API)

Comment: A kernel is compiled differently than C++ code. Also there is no such thing as C/C++

Comment: Those functions in the C++ standard libraries represent compiled x86 code.  That is not usable on a GPU.  You could not possibly be using those math functions on a GPU.

Answer (score 3):

`nvcc` and the CUDA toolchain automatically manage this for you.

There is nothing required to ensure that this works correctly except reading the CUDA math API [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/index.html#axzz4aw5Fij29) and using a supported host compiler version with nvcc on your platform of choice.